# How can I get an after update trigger to work when it is being fired from an after insert trigger in mysql?

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hello, every one :)!

I'll try and keep this as simple as possible, basically, I have one table that references itself via a parent_id column.  Each row in the table can have a parent and can keep count of how many children it has via the count column.  So essentially what I'm trying to do is have the triggers update each parent row's count column when necessary

The problem is that the update trigger gets called when the update operation in the insert trigger gets called.  Then I get:

***"General error: 1442 Can't update table 'term_taxonomies' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger"***.

Any ideas?

Actual code:

```
TRIGGER `dbname`.`ai_term_taxonomies`
AFTER INSERT ON `dbname`.`term_taxonomies`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.parent_id NOT 0 THEN
        UPDATE term_taxonomies as termTax SET assocItemCount = (assocItemCount + 1)
        WHERE termTax.term_taxonomy_id = NEW.parent_id; 
    END IF;

END$$

CREATE
TRIGGER `dbname`.`au_term_taxonomies`
AFTER UPDATE ON `dbname`.`term_taxonomies`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    IF NEW.parent_id NOT OLD.parent_id THEN
        IF NEW.parent_id NOT 0 THEN
            UPDATE term_taxonomies as termTax SET assocItemCount = (assocItemCount + 1)
            WHERE termTax.term_taxonomy_id = NEW.parent_id; 
        END IF;
        IF OLD.parent_id NOT 0 THEN
            UPDATE term_taxonomies as termTax SET assocItemCount = (assocItemCount - 1)
            WHERE termTax.term_taxonomy_id = OLD.parent_id; 
        END IF;
    END IF;

END$$
```

Answer (score 0):

All mysql triggers execute in the same transaction as the triggering statement.

You want to update using the `SET NEW.assocItemCount` syntax as opposed to performing an `UPDATE` statement on the underlying table.

**Edit**:  However, in your case this is not possible because you are updating a different row in the same table, the hardest thing to do in a mysql trigger.  Sorry.

You will have to change your schema.  Take `assocItemCount` out of your table, create a new table holding just `term_taxonomy_id` and `assocItemCount`, and update that using an `UPDATE` statement from your query.  It is also possible to use a view joining these two tables to hide this detail if a query needs to use your original schema.

Alternatively, if you did not have `assocItemCount` in your database at all, you would still be able to compute it in any queries, and your database would be better normalized than it is now.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but in this case we are updating a different row, so how do we tell the engine to update that particular row?  Ahhh!  I get what you're saying! But in this case the update trigger serves two purposes.  To keep count on an insert and to update counts on an update.

Comment: Can I use SET NEW.assocItemCount, they way you recommend, and specify a WHERE clause within the same statement?

Comment: @user437498 - Unfortunately you can't.  You will have to change your schema.  Take `assocItemCount` out of your table, create a new table holding just `term_taxonomy_id` and `assocItemCount`, and update that using an `UPDATE` statement from your query.

Comment: AAAAHHHH!!  Looks like I have no choice.  Thanks Jirka :-D!